# How to select an appropriate Nvidia GPU for learning CUDA

Tags: parallel-programming, gpu

What would be a good GPU to start learning CUDA on?

Are any GPUs unsuitable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Virtually any card made by nVidia in the last 5 years can be used to run CUDA programs. In terms of "Best", you'd probably want a [Tesla](http://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla-supercomputing-solutions.html) but they are hideously expensive. By hideously expensive, I mean that they are designed to operate only as computing on GPU hardware and not as regular graphics cards. You mount them in servers and "**[Do Science](http://www.topatoco.com/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Store_Code=TO&Product_Code=DC-BISCUIT&Category_Code=DC-SHIRTS)**" to things with them. You can technically mount one in a workstation but it's still expensive. A [bare minimum](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?c=us&cs=555&fb=1&l=en&model_id=precision-t5600&oc=mlb1846&s=biz&vw=classic) machine from Dell, for example, is just under $5000.

As far as home applications, whatever card you've got would probably work fine provided that it's on this [list](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gpus). Pick something you can afford. Find some problems that are of interest and amenable to the [SIMD](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#Models)(SPMD) architecture and have at it. Finding a [reference](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025108.do) for C is recommended as well as a [CUDA guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf). If you don't yet know any C, [Zed Shaw](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/) will cure you of that.